# Use query time range when the expression requires explicit value

Tags: kql, azure-log-analytics

When entering a query in Azure LogAnalytics, there is an input field above the query window to specify *Time Range*, unless there is a constraint on the `timestamp` column, in which case it shows *Set In Query*. Since I am using `make-series` operator (to fill in zeroes for the minutes that have no data), I have to provide it in the query, because the `make-series` operator otherwise starts at the first entry that has data while I want it to start at the start of the range. So, it is normally not a problem to put something like `ago(1d)` into the query, *but:*

Dashboards have their own *Time Range* input field, and when the query uses a different timestamp, it a. does not match the other graphs and 2. shows a very obnoxious info message stating that (I want that screen space for myself!).

So, can I explicitly reference the time range from that input field in the query?

Comment: I found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/dashboard-parameters) that for *data explorer* dashboards, the parameters are `_startTime` and `_endTime`, but it does not work in azure dashboard with log analytics query (I just tried, it says unknown identifier).

Comment: Can you share some dummy logs, and the dashboard error to be able to reproduce? Time Range can be used as an Operator across a Workbook/Dashboard.

Comment: These are typical parameters in other platforms like Sumo. Odd this isn't something obvious in Azure